# What is required to trigger a vote in UK parliament and what makes it ‘binding’?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

News articles mention many methods such as ‘motions’ and most recently noticed ‘praying against’.

As a novice outside observer one would have thought there would be an established and clear process for our democratically elected representives to decide what to vote on and what power the decision should have.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Parliament_in_the_United_Kingdom#Stages_of_a_bill

Comment: This should all be described in Erskine May, although that's the opposite of clear. I think to a great extent MPs *like* the medieval obscurity of the process...

Comment: (Yes, it's a >£300 book. I believe pirate PDFs are available somewhere. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Erskine-May-Parliamentary-Malcolm-Jack/dp/1405751061 )

Answer (score 2):

The clearest form which creates something "binding" is the process which leads to an "Act of Parliament" This involves a formal bill being presented to the house three times, passing a series of votes (firstly on the general principals, then on particular amendments, finally on the detailed wording) Followed by consideration by the Lords (who may amend) reconsideration by the Commons (who may reverse the amendments) until an agreed text is passed by both Houses (or the Commons invokes the Parliament act to pass the bill without the consent of the Lords), and then finally the formality of Royal Assent.

This process creates new laws, which judges can refer to. It can legally bind any body subject to the Laws in the UK, except Parliament itself.

Other votes, motions, processes of Parliament are less "binding". They tend to have the effect of stating "This House believes...". For example there is the "Humble address", which is a message to be sent to the Queen. This is binding in that the Government must act on it: it might require that the government release some papers or information. The government must do this. But the "Humble address" does not create new laws. A judge cannot refer to a humble address in deciding some legal question.

Substantive motions call for action or express an opinion, but they do not create new laws. They are not absolutely binding, but can be used by the government as part of its consultative process in forming policy. Substantive motions can be amended, with the Speaker's permission and approval from the House.

At the least "binding" end are motions worded as "This house has considered..." This allows for a topic to be discussed without given the House giving an opinion Such "General motion" can't be amended, as they just state that the house has considered a matter.

Early Day Motions are topics which an MP can sign to express interest in, but with the knowledge that they won't actually be debated. They can be used as a mechanism to raise interest in a particular topic.

Much of these descriptions can be found on the [MP's guide to procedure](https://beta.parliament.uk/collections/6i8XQAfD), the details are doubtless more arcane and complex. The processes have evolved rather than being designed, which explains much of their opacity.

Comment: "It can legally bind any body subject to the Laws in the UK, except Parliament itself." I assume you refer to the fact that Parliament can vote to remove it; however Parliament also are bound to follow the law all the time it has not been repealed (save for any law which would make itself irrepealable.)